# Browser is not printing hard coded persian characters in codeigniter-3

Tags: php, utf-8, codeigniter-3, content-type, farsi

I am trying to print URL by using below:

$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

It prints english URL fine but persian URL shows as below:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/8897-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%B9%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D8%B1%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AC?lang=per"/>
```

Though the fields which are selected from database print in persian fine as below:

```
<title>اینٹیک روینج</title>
```

But when saved in php file (hard coded) turns into ?????? after saving.

snapshot of the  is as below:

`<title>اینٹیک روینج</title>` ------> This is persian script what is selected from Database

`<meta property="og:title" content="??????????">`   -----> This is the persian script as above which was saved directly in this php file

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/7657-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%B9%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D8%B1%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%86%D8%AC?lang=per"/>`   -----> This is he persian script what we capture from URL

Though to compare URL part with stored slug urldecode(auto_link($url)); works fine but I need to print them to show canonical URL

1. My Server host is RHEL 7 and I am using php 5.6, php.ini
   configuration is:

   ; PHP's default character set is set to UTF-8.

   ; http://php.net/default-charset

   default_charset = "UTF-8"
2. For more information  -> I have the setting in codeigniter 3
   config.php as:

   ```
   $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
   ```
3. I have declared below in html head:
4. Also in php I have declared

   ```
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"');
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print your URL: `https://www.example.com/8897-اینٹیک-روینج?lang=per`

Use this

`$url = urldecode((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");`

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?=$url?>"/>
```

or you can do it in a single line

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?=urldecode($url)?>"/>
```

Comment: Hi Murad, Thanks for this, browser part is resolved but the persian characters saved in the files (under application/views/) still convert to "??????".

Comment: May I know the characters are in the database or inside a view file, if it is in the database make sure it's in the Persian characters in the database!
If it is in the view file can show me a sample?

Comment: The characters were in the file, I discovered that the editor I used was winscp internal editor which does not support utf-8, Thanks